# Como retornar un vector en Java

Tags: java

tengo este codigo lo que quiero es retornar el vector para que sea mandado a otro metodo void y presentar la suma de los vectores.Pero no logro retornar el vector completo.

```
import java.util.Random;


public class sumaVectores {
static int sumarVectores(int vectorA[],int vectorB[]){
   // int vectorVA[]=new int [10];
    int sum[]=new int [10];
    int a=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<vectorA.length;i++){
       sum[i]= vectorA[i]+vectorB[i];
       //a=sum[i];
       
    }
    return sum;
}
```

quiero que este metodo retorne el vector sumado pero no logro hacerlo.

```
static void presentarDatos (int suma[]){
    int salida=0;
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++){
       // salida= suma[i];
    System.out.println("El valor " + (i+1) +" es: "+suma[i]);
    }
}
```

y presentar esa suma de vectores en este void.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    int a=0;
    int suma []=new int [10];
    int vectorA[] = new int[10];
    int vectorB[] = new int[10];
    Random aleatorio = new Random ();
    for( int i=0;i<vectorA.length;i++){
        vectorA[i]= aleatorio.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println("Valor del vector A N."+(i+1)+" es: "+vectorA[i]);
    }
    for( int i=0;i<vectorB.length;i++){
        vectorB[i]= aleatorio.nextInt(100);
        System.out.println("Valor del vector B N."+(i+1)+" es: "+vectorB[i]);
    }
    
    
    sumarVectores(vectorA,vectorB);
    
    presentarDatos(suma);
}
```

}
me sale el siguiente mensaje de error

[image: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QwYDF.png]

Comment: La declaración del método dice que retorna `int` (`static int sumarVectores(...`). Decláralo para que retorne el arreglo de int.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu metodo `sumarVectores` debe ser del mismo tipo que el retorno tu estas retornando sum que es un `array` de tipo `int` por ende tu método debe ser de tipo array int

```
static int[]sumarVectores(int vectorA[],int vectorB[])
```

ahora en el main concatena tus métodos

```
presentarDatos(sumarVectores(vectorA,vectorB));
```